# Unable to execute command

Tags: c#, discord.net

I wrote a simple module for my discord bot.

Bot:

```
_client = new DiscordSocketClient();
_commandService = new CommandService();

_serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
     .AddSingleton(_client)
     .AddSingleton(_commandService)
     .BuildServiceProvider();
```

Module:

```
public class MyModule: ModuleBase<ICommandContext>
{
    private readonly MyService _service;

    public MyModule(MyService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    [Command("DoStuff", RunMode = RunMode.Async)]
    public async Task DoStuffCmd()
    {
        await _service.DoStuff(Context.Guild, (Context.User as IVoiceState).VoiceChannel);
    }
}
```

Modules get added like this:

```
await _commandService.AddModulesAsync(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly());
```

Adding the Module explicit will result in the exception that this modlue has already been added, so i assume it worked.

I handle the Command like this.

```
// Create a number to track where the prefix ends and the command begins
int argPos = 0;
// Determine if the message is a command, based on if it starts with '!' or a mention prefix
if (!(message.HasCharPrefix('!', ref argPos) || message.HasMentionPrefix(_client.CurrentUser, ref argPos))) return;
// Create a Command Context
var context = new CommandContext(_client, message);
// Execute the command. (result does not indicate a return value, 
// rather an object stating if the command executed successfully)
var result = await _commandService.ExecuteAsync(context, argPos, _serviceProvider);
```

The `result` variable always returns `Success` but `DoStuffCmd` Method in `MyModule` never gets called.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't seem to inject the `MyService` into your `ServiceCollection`.
If you do not inject the service, your module can never be created, as you defined it as a dependency

```
private readonly MyService _service;
public MyModule(MyService service)
{
    _service = service;
}
```

To fix this you can add your `MyService` to the `ServiceCollection`.
To do this, it would be best to Create a `IMyService` (interface) and add this to your  injections as such

```
_serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
 .AddSingleton(_client)
 .AddSingleton(_commandService)
 .AddSingleton<IMyService, MyService>()
 .BuildServiceProvider();
```